# how to change line in php

Tags: php, html, mongodb, ubuntu

i am using mongo db and am looping through my collection in mongodb to display all contents in my webpage. however,they are all displaying in a single line. How to make them break line?

below is my code i have tried:

```
$name=$_SESSION['name'];

$m = new MongoClient();
//echo "Connection to database successfully <br>";

$db = $m->SAHC;
//echo "Database mydb selected <br>";

$collection = $db->upload_files;
//echo "Collection selected successfully <br>";


$document = array("usrName"=>$name);

$cursor=$collection->find($document);

session_start();
// iterate cursor to display title of documents
echo "<table width='auto'  style='border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 20px' ><tr>";
foreach ($cursor as $document) {

    echo "<td >";

    $value=$document["fileName"];
    $value2=$document["uploadSize"];


    $_SESSION['rootFolder']=$value;

    echo '<input type="image" src="images/file2.png"  value="'.$value2.'" class="btTxt submit" width="85" onclick="myfunc(this.value)"><b>'.$value . "</b>";
    echo "</td>";

}

echo "</tr></table>";

?>
```

Comment: `<td>` is for cells in a single row, `<tr>` is for new rows. Place the `<tr></tr>` inside of your loop.

Comment: thank you so much.. it works :D